# Dynamic menu table in inner pages

Tags: joomla

I want to add dynamic menu table in inner pages based upon the tabs on the home page.
how to do that in joomla,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a split menu where the link you click at the top determines the menu that shows up in a column/below. This is the native behavior for Joomla menus simply by setting the start and end levels in the menu module. Here is a good tutorial -

http://www.theartofjoomla.com/magazine/article/27-more-menu-tricks-the-split-menu-technique.html

Answer (score 0):

Beware:: The split level menu feature in Joomla only works when the split equals TWO levels.  If you want to build your site with a single master menu that spans 3 or more levels, this does not work.  It looks like the internals of Joomla do not know how to track the parent properly (not really sure) when the menus are generated (probably an overstatement).  Level 1:1 works, Level 2:2 works but then when you try to specify a menu starting at level 3, it breaks.  In my case, I hacked the menu to check the pathways (breadcrumbs) list and derive what I wanted from it so I could determine the real parent of the items at level 3 (or other).  Then I could get the items to generate proper.  This was a disappointment in Joomla (v1.7).  And then on top of this, you would then have to hack further to ensure that each menu item instance starting at 1 is highlighted proper.  Perhaps the menus should be more closely coupled to the breadcrumbs pathway list.